# Build JNI with Custom Build tool

Tags: android, c++, java-native-interface, native, build-tools

I am trying to build a JNI Layer. New to this but from what I understand, JNI package is built using both Android SDK and Android NDK.
Here, I need to substitute the Android NDK with something else, something custom.

Looking for any high level thoughts or strategies.

Comment: Your question is way too vague to answer. You can build JNI libraries using any native tooling that produces libraries, the NDK just happens to ship toolchains, libraries, and platform headers that allow you to do so _for Android_. If you want to build native code using OCaml cross-compiled on a Raspberry Pi, nobody is going to stop you.